# JS countdown working on PC, but not on iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone

I used the below code to create a countdown timer and it works fine on a PC, but not on an iPhone (shows NaN on phone). I don't have any errors showing up in the console. I've tried it on several phones, each has the same issue.

Markdown:

```
<div id="cdtimer"> <br>
<h1>Opening in</h1> <br>
<div id="clockdiv">
  <div>
    <span class="days"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Days</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="hours"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Hours</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="minutes"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Minutes</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="seconds"></span>
    <div class="smalltext">Seconds</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
      function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
      var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
      var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
      var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
      var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
      var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      return {
        'total': t,
        'days': days,
        'hours': hours,
        'minutes': minutes,
        'seconds': seconds
      };
    }

    function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
      var clock = document.getElementById(id);
      var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
      var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
      var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
      var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

      function updateClock() {
        var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

        daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
        hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
        minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
        secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

        if (t.total <= 0) {
          clearInterval(timeinterval);
        }
      }

      updateClock();
      var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
    }


    var deadline = '2016-12-9';
    initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

What could be the cause of such an issue?

Comment: You'll need to do some debugging and identify which line(s) in the .js are not doing what you'd expect it to do when its executed on the iPhone.

Comment: @RJM - how would I do this debugging?